# Bootstrap DatePicker binding in Knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker and binding the selected date with knockoutjs in an asp.net mvc application

Knockout Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
          //initialize datepicker with some optional options
          var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {
              useCurrent: false,
              format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
          };
          $(element).datepicker(options);

          //when a user changes the date, update the view model
          ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
               var value = valueAccessor();
               if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                   value(event.date);
               }
          });
      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
          var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
          //when the view model is updated, update the widget
          if (widget) {
              widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
              widget.setValue();
          }
      }
 };

 var model = {
    StartDate: ko.observable(),
    EndDate: ko.observable()
 };

 ko.applyBindings(model, $("#target")[0]);
```

[Jsfiddle of what I have done.](https://jsfiddle.net/3t8cbcof/1/)

Right now, after completing the form, the form is submitted to the server using ajax post.

On return, I want to clear the selected start and end dates input fields.

I have tried this:

```
self.StartDate(null);
self.EndDate(null);
```

this clears the properties, but the input still retains the selected dates. Is there a way to clear not just the properties, but also the input values?

Also, in the knockout custom binding init function, is there a way to link both date inputs to make it a range, like the demo [here](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)? In the demo, when Range radio button is selected, but fields work together as a range.

Comment: In your update method, you just need to set the value of the input to the value of unwrapped observable. So e.g. define value `var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());` then last line in your update, you could do `$(element).val(value);` to change the input value which datepicker component is giving (observable is changed normally, so no worries here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following **Kasperoo** suggestion:

Changing this:

```
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");

        if (widget) {
           widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
           widget.setValue();
        }
  }
```

to

```
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(value);
  }
```

helped clear the fields on server post back.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using this [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), and the API call to set the widget date to the KO date when clearing (or setting any date via KO) is incorrect in the binder `update` function.

This works (see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joewilson/3t8cbcof/7/)):

```
$(element).datepicker("update", ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
```